# WebLogic changes the url-pattern of RESTful

Tags: rest, jersey, weblogic

After deploying my war file, Weblogic changes the url-pattern, which i've defined in web.xml for my Jersey RESTful. As you can see, I want to access my service under /rest/* but weblogic changes it to /resources/*. Where can I configure it for WebLogic?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>ch.ni.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

p.s it works with tomcat, as desired

Comment: no one has an answer for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem moving an application from Glassfish 3 to Weblogic 12.2.1. I finally caved in and followed the Jersey tutorial [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.21/getting-started.html).
I used the web.xml that was generated in the example to fix the code I was working on. 
Short answer is I had to change the web.xml servlet definition to look like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>your.package.with.JAXRS.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also took the dependencies from the POM in the example and used them in my POM.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it helps.